# $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h^{1/q}} = 0$ for $F(x)=\int^{x}_{0}f(t)dt$ for $f \in L^{p}[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $F(x) = \int^{x}_{0} f(t)dt$ for $f \in L^{p}([0,1])$ for $1 <p< \infty$, then $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h^{1-1/p}} = 0.$$

This looks somewhat similar to the [Lebesgue differentiation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem), but the exponent in the denominator is throwing me off a bit.

Comment: I guess you mean equals and not limit arrow. So the limit is pointwise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Apply Holder's inequality to $$F(x+h)-F(x)=\int_x^{x+h}f(t)\,dt\quad(h>0).$$

### Hmm...

Maybe I should note that there's more than one way to apply Holder here. The most naive application gives $$|F(x+h)-F(x)|\le||f'||_ph^q,$$which is not quite good enough. But instead write $\int_x^{x+h}f'=\int(f'\chi_{[x,x+h]})(\chi_{[x,x+h]})$ and apply Holder to *that* product...

Comment: So is it helpful in this case to think of $\int^{x+h}_{x} f(t)dt$ as $\int_{[0,1]} f(t) \chi_{[x,x+h]}(t) dt$?

Comment: @user135520 Exactly

Comment: @user135520 Maybe "exactly" was too strong - see revised version

Comment: @user135520 Actually with the former we don't even get (directly) that the limit _exists_; yes, it shows the limit is bounded by $||f||_p$ if it does exist.

Comment: I had some typos in previous comments. But with the former estimate, we only obtain that limit (if it exists) is bounded, with the new estimate, we obtain that the limit is bounded by $\|f\chi_{[x,x+h]}|_{p}$ which tends to $0$ as $h \to 0$ by DCT.

Comment: @user135520 Yes, this time it really is exactly right.